# how can I pass parameters from Express route to Node middleware

Tags: node.js, express, keystonejs

I couldn't find an answer in the docs, and I'm hoping there's a way to do what I need.  I have some express routes:

```
app.post( '/submit-agency-event'            , eventService.submitEvent );
app.post( '/submit-question'                , formService.submitQuestion );
app.post( '/submit-information-request'     , formService.submitInformationRequest );
app.post( '/social-worker-register-family'  , familyService.registerFamily );
```

where each route uses a function in a middleware file to process the request.  I'd like to restrict one route to only a few userTypes (which is stored on `req.user.userType`).  I'd like to set up the route similar to the following:

```
app.post( '/social-worker-register-child'   , middleware.requireUsersOfType( ['admin, social worker'] ), childService.registerChild );
```

then use the function `requireUsersOfType()` to handle processing and any needed redirects before `childService.registerChild()` is called.

```
exports.requireUsersOfType = ( req, res, next, userTypesArray ) => {
    // processing
};
```

What I can't seem to figure out is how to pass parameters into the `requireUsersOfType()` function.  Does anyone know how this can be done?

Answer (score 0):

You can use [Closures](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Closures):

> A closure is the combination of a function and the lexical environment
>   within which that function was declared.

Example:

```
exports.requireUsersOfType = (userTypesArray) => {
  return function(req, res, next) => {
    // your code...
  } 
};
```

Answer (score 0):

While not the most elegant solution, if you can't get it working as others have suggested, this should do the trick:

```
app.post( '/social-worker-register-child', function( req, res, next ) { middleware.requireUsersOfType( req, res, next, userTypes = ['admin, social worker'] ); }, childService.registerChild );
```

You should then be able to do your processing in middleware as desired:

```
exports.requireUsersOfType = ( req, res, next, userTypesArray ) => {
    // processing
};
```